# Computing Gaussian Mixture Model with Expectation Maximization using Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce, mixture-model, expectation-maximization

Where I can find a Mapreduce implementation(or tutorial) for computing GMM using EM?
Also is it really feasible to do it using mapreduce framework?

I have found this lecture [link](https://github.com/lintool/MapReduce-course-2013s/blob/master/slides/session07.pdf) but it does not contains detail description, also if my data(mean and variance) is large then how do I pass it from mapper to reducer?

Comment: Have you tried to implement the EM algorithm of GMM on a single machine?

Comment: yes ..I have implemented that using matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, You said, you have experience implementing EM algorithm. It's easy to explain.

## EM algorithm

As you know, EM algorithm is an iterative method for finding maximum likelihood. One iteration is consist of two steps that Expectation(E-step) and Maximization step (M-step).

In **E-step**, the likelihoods of the samples are calculated from the previous model. Let `n` be the number of samples, we can get `n` likelihoods.

---

Here, the likelihood calculation is performed independently. So this can be performed using multi-processor environment.

---

Assume that we have 4 CPUs on single machine, `n/4` likelihoods can are calculated by each CPU. It's 4 times faster (the IO time is ignored)

In **M-step**, the new model is derived by the likelihoods.

## To mapreduce

### Computation EM

- E-step can be extend to `mapper` tasks on mapreduce because of independent each other samples.

  - input

    - key: anything
    - value: a sample
  - output

    - key: anything
    - value: likelihood of the input sample
- M-step can be extend to `reducer` task (this can be multiple reducers, but simply I recommend one reducer).

  - input

    - key: anything
    - value: likelihood
  - output

    - key: anything
    - value: the next model

### data representation

- the training samples are located at some directory on `HDFS`

  - this will be input of `mapreduce`
- the previous model is also located at `HDFS` but different directory to training samples

  - **USE** distributed cache to let `mappers` know where the model is

### iteration

One mapreduce task is analogues to one iteration of EM algorithm. So you need to iterate the next mapreduce task until converged

I have explained briefly. You will face many problems while you implement.

I hope this helps.